# latency time for three types of replication such as snapshot, transactional and merge

Tags: ssh, raid, security

i want to compute latency time for each type of replication with c# and then i want to compare these three types, that can be possible or not. what can i do for this performance? how can i compute latency time for three types of replication.

Answer (score 1):

Try         them.